# What is the subject of「あけましておめでとう」?

Tags: set-phrases

「あける」、 regardless of the kanji, is transitive. *Therefore*:

While the object is「新年」、 what is the subject of「あけましておめでとう」?
Regardless of what the subject is, is 「あけましておめでとうございます」 a metaphor?

Comment: 明ける〔 **自** 下一〕（1）夜が終わって朝になる。（2） **古い年・月が終わって、新しい年・月になる。** （3）ある時間が終わる。◆「開ける」と同語源。

Comment: @blutorange I stand corrected with regard to assuming it was transitive. I sure thought there were rules for easily identifying transitive / intransitive verbs.

Comment: This is a greeting, not a regular sentence.  It looks pretty weird trying to find a subject or object in it.

Comment: I had the same feeling as @l'électeur, but if we consider this as a question of etymology, I think it could make sense to ask.  (In other words, where does this phrase come from?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

あける (明ける in kanji) here is an *intransitive* verb which basically means *to finish*, *to change to a new state*, etc. According to [大辞林](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%98%8E%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E3%83%BB%E7%A9%BA%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E3%83%BB%E9%96%8B%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B-195514):

> あける【明ける・空ける・開ける】
>   二**（自動詞）**
>   ①夜が終わって朝になり，あたりが明るくなる。 《明》 ↔ 暮れる 「夜（よ）が－・ける」
>   ②時間が経過して次の新しい年・日や季節が始まる。主語を示すことはない。 《明》 ↔ 暮れる 「 － ・けて八月二日，いよいよ頂上をめざす日だ」
>   ③ある特別の状態の期間が終わって，普通の状態に戻る。おわる。 《明》 「長かった梅雨（つゆ）がようやく－・けた」 「喪（も）が－・ける」 「年季が－・ける」

So the implied subject of あける in あけましておめでとう is 年 or 新年.

Comment: That is so surprising to me. Not only the meaning, but also the transitivity of a verb depends on the kanji. Had I done the research that I should have done before posting, I would have discovered this. Thanks for investing your time to help me.

Comment: Come to think of it, 明ける sometimes means 終わる but sometimes means 始まる...

Comment: @user312440 I think you're thinking of that backwards. There's a word pronounced あける that's intransitive. When this is the case and with the right meaning, it gets written out as 明ける but I could be wrong on this